# how do I count for every index a unique value. so I can make an data structure tree

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

i have a data set with column names and I have to make an tree in python for these column names. I have everything in an list:
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C2', 'TR2', 'AR4']` 
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C2', 'TR3', 'AR3']` 
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C1', 'TR1', 'AR1']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C1', 'TR3', 'AR5']` 
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C4', 'TR2', 'AR1']` 
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C4', 'TR1', 'AR3']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C4', 'TR1', 'AR1']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C2', 'TR2', 'AR3']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C2', 'TR3', 'AR4']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C1', 'TR2', 'AR5']`
`['HoPE', 'FA', 'exp', 'TX', 'C3', 'TR1', 'AR2']`
`i have more but for now its enough.
i have to find a way to tell python that C1 is a Parent of TR1,TR2,TR3 and every TR is a parent for 5 AR. (so I have 3 C's every C has 3 TR's and every TR has 5 AR's.
how do I do this

this is my code and what im working on:

```
import pandas as pd


def read_it(file):

    df_raw = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')

    return df_raw


def remove_elements(df_raw):

    df_wide = df_raw
    new_df = df_wide.columns = ['_'.join(col.split('_')[:7]) for col in
                       df_wide.columns]
    headers = new_df[10:]
    return headers



def split_elements(headers):
    all_list =[]
    for line in headers:

        all = line.split('_')

        print(all)


def give_unique_elements(list):

    list_index =[]
    for index in list:
        experiment = index[0]
        celltype = index[1]
        genetype = index[2]
        timepoint = index[3]
        conditions = index[4]
        techincal_rep = index[5]
        analytical_rep = index[6]



if __name__ == '__main__':

    all = []

    file = 'HoPE_FC_2023-05_DIA-MBR_FA-mat-exp_results.pr_matrix.tsv'
    df_raw = read_it(file)
    headers = remove_elements(df_raw)
    all_list = split_elements(headers)
    give_unique_elements(all_list)
```

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? You want to build a graph, and then? What is the exact expected output?

Comment: FYI, your graph [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHV0Y.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. You have explained your input structure, and that you want to find parent-child relations. But what exactly do you expect as output for this input?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.